# Problem with percentage width and flex layout in nicegui and tailwindcss

Tags: python, css, tailwind-css, nicegui

I want to make a flex layout with nicegui. I stumbled over a weird behavior when using percentage sizes. Can anyone please point out, what I did wrong?

Here is a minimal example, where I expected the two red boxes to be next to each other.
However, the second box is below the first one. Only when I remove the `gap-1` class, the boxes are next to each other.

```py
from nicegui import ui

with ui.row().classes("w-96 gap-1 bg-grey"):
    ui.label("Wurst").classes("w-1/2 bg-red")
    ui.label("Wurst").classes("w-1/2 bg-red")

ui.run(title="test")
```

So I thought, the nicegui css-classes might be the problem, but I can reproduce the same behavior with tailwindcss directly:

```py
ui.html(
    """
    <div class="w-96 flex flex-row bg-grey gap-1">
    <div class="w-1/2 bg-red">w-1/2</div>
    <div class="w-1/2 bg-red">w-1/2</div>
    </div>
  """
)
```

You can even paste the above html code into the https://play.tailwindcss.com/ and see that the boxes are in the same line

A workaround is this code. Somehow the tailwind behavior that calculates the width of elements including the margin is not preserved in nicegui.

```py
from nicegui import ui

with ui.row().classes("w-96 gap-1 bg-grey"):
    ui.label("Wurst").classes("w-[calc(50%-2px)] bg-red")
    ui.label("Wurst").classes("w-[calc(50%-2px)] bg-red")
    ui.label("Wurst").classes("w-[calc(50%-2px)] bg-red")
    ui.label("Wurst").classes("w-[calc(50%-2px)] bg-red")
    ui.label("Wurst").classes("w-[calc(50%-2px)] bg-red")
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that 50% + gap + 50% is more than 100%. Therefore the flex layout automatically wraps the second box onto the next "line".

You can avoid this behavior using the Tailwind class "no-wrap":

```py
with ui.row().classes("w-96 gap-1 bg-grey no-wrap"):
    ui.label("Wurst").classes("w-1/2 bg-red")
    ui.label("Wurst").classes("w-1/2 bg-red")
```

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is, that I want it to be wrapped when I add more of these („Wurst“) boxes. How come that this code works with just using tailwindcss? According to the tailwind documentation, it should stay in one line. I even copy and pasted the equivalent code from the tailwind documentation and got wrapped boxes. Or you can paste the above html code into (https://play.tailwindcss.com/) and see that it keeps it in one line.

Comment: @Dronakuul Interesting. I don't understand why it's not wrapping on their playground. Maybe it's the combination of TailwindCSS with Quasar, which applies some CSS itself.

Comment: To check that, I went into developer mode in the browser and disabled the quasar CSS classes. Still no effect. I wondered, if nicegui somehow configures tailwind.config.js